# Post file with non english filename

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization

I am trying to Put a file with non latin name to the API using the below code in C#. It works well for files with latin names. But when the fileName is in Arabic, Chinese or Korean, the file name on the server side become gibberish. I can not find a way to set the encoding for file name. I have tried the UTF8Encoding  but it doesn't work. Any idea on how to make the below code to work with non-english file names?

```
attachmentData = myfile;
var urlParameters = "urlToPost";
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Headers.Add("cguid", Api.MyLoginCredential.cguid);
content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(attachmentData, 0, attachmentData.Count()), "arabic or chinesse name", "arabic or chinesse filename");
var response = client.PutAsync(urlParameters, content, cts.Token).Result;
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Non-ASCII values are automatically converted to UTF-8. If I use your code with a filename of "日本語.txt" I get `form-data; name="=?utf-8?B?5pel5pys6KqeLnR4dA==?="; filename="=?utf-8?B?5pel5pys6KqeLnR4dA==?="; filename*=utf-8''%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E.txt`. So everything seems fine. Maybe the receiving end is making a mistake?

Comment: I see the same ?utf-8? being send to server however it is not being decoded and still shows exactly the same string. The server is in asp.net c#, any pointer on how to decode it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Uri.EscapeDataString(YourString)

Example:

content.Headers.Add("filename", Uri.EscapeDataString(InputFilename));

Cheers!